# VUE - Global hook to check if all components loaded

Tags: vue.js, components, hook, mounted-volumes

I want to run a function every time a new page is loaded, for example when a view (home.vue, contact.vue, ...) is mounted.

I don't want to call this function on each view from the mounted hook. Is there a way to check, maybe from the app.js, if all components have mounted? Something like `this.allMounted --> true/false` :)

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: You can call the function in the mounted hook of `App.vue`. That's how I usually do it